# Receiving message from receiver app to sender app iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, chromecast

I have an app which can communicate with Chromecast.

I have my receiver app in web. I am facing issues when I am trying to receive messages from receiver end.

I have tried to subclass the GCKCastChannel and using the namespace, I am trying to see the message in didReceiveTextMessage message and it seems like, its not being called.

Can any one let me know how would I receive message from receiver in iOS app?

I have made a class named TextChannel

```
import Foundation


  class TextChannel : GCKCastChannel {

    override func didReceiveTextMessage(_ message: String) {
    print("Received message: \(message)")
    //Notification
}
}
```

In my ViewController I have the following code

```
 private lazy var textChannel:TextChannel = {
    return TextChannel(namespace: "urn:x-cast:examok.awesome.example")
}()
```

Comment: are you invoke the delegate to current class

Comment: can you show your tried code

Comment: I have added the code. In android end, we are able to see the received message however I am not sure of how to get the message.

Comment: add `GCKGenericChannelDelegate` in your class and try

Comment: as well as import the header `#import <GoogleCast/GCKGenericChannel.h>
`

Comment: Do I delegate this to textChannel?

Comment: yes, its working in based on delegate

Comment: No,  textChannel has not property delegate how to delegate this?

Comment: Thank you all.. I resolved the issue using the GCKGenericChannel.h

Comment: good and great bro